# Add Users Who React To Reaction To Embed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Trying to make a bot that when the users click on the reaction there discord id goes into an embed Field and if they un click or click another emoji they end up in the field. This is gonna be used for a voting bot that once a certain number of users click yes or no a decision will be made to accept a user or deny a user. Any help?

```
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  message.delete({ timeout: 100 });
  if (!args[0]) return message.reply('You need to supply the question');

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(args.join(' '))
    .setDescription('Poll created by ' + message.author.tag)
    .addField('Status', 'Voting is currently open.')
    .setColor('#ffd700')
    .attachFiles(new Discord.MessageAttachment('https://i.imgur.com/QUmbq9o.png', 'thumbnail.png'))
    .setThumbnail('attachment://thumbnail.png')
    .setFooter('Bot created by James (Rock)₇₇₇');

  message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
    await msg.react('');
    await msg.react('');
    await msg.react('');
    await msg.react('️');

    const threshold = 6;

    async function stop(result) {
      collector.stop();

      const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(msg.embeds[0]);

      newEmbed.title = newEmbed.title + ' [CLOSED]';
      newEmbed.fields[0] = { name: 'Status', value: 'Voting is now closed.\n' + result };
      newEmbed.setThumbnail('attachment://thumbnail.png');
      await msg.edit(newEmbed);

      msg.reactions.removeAll();
    }

    async function update() {
      const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(embed);

      const userYes = (votes[''].size === 0)? '-' : [...votes['']];
      const userNo = (votes[''].size === 0)? '-' : [...votes['']];
      const userUnsure = (votes[''].size === 0)? '-' : [...votes['']];

      newEmbed.addFields(
        { name: `User Yes (${votes[''].size}/${threshold})`, value: userYes, inline: true },
        { name: `User No (${votes[''].size}/${threshold})`, value: userNo, inline: true },
        { name: 'User Unsure', value: userUnsure, inline: true }
      );

      await msg.edit(newEmbed);

      if (votes[''].size >= threshold) {
        await stop('This answer is good enough to get accepted and an upvote.');
        // do something
      } else if (votes[''].size >= threshold) {
        await stop('This answer is not good enough to get accepted and an upvote.');
        // do something
      }
    }

    const votes = {
      '': new Set(),
      '': new Set(),
      '': new Set(),
      '️': new Set()
    };

    update();

    const collector = msg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => !user.bot , { dispose: true });

    collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
      if (['', '', '', '️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)) {
        const userReactions = msg.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(user.id));

        for (const userReaction of userReactions.values()) {
          if (userReaction.emoji.name !== reaction.emoji.name || reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
            userReaction.users.remove(user.id);
            votes[userReaction.emoji.name].delete(user);
          }
        }

        votes[reaction.emoji.name].add(user);
      } else {
        reaction.remove();
      }

      update();
    });

    collector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
      votes[reaction.emoji.name].delete(user);

      update();
    });
  });

};

module.exports.help = {
  name: "poll"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *they end up in the inline field*?

Comment: The user who clicks the thumbs up gets put into a embed showing everyone there username voted thumbs up or if you click thumbs down your username pops up in the that field.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? From your question I'm having trouble understanding what the actual problem is

Comment: The embed pops up the reactions pop up but i want it to input the users names who click the reactions inside the embed live in the channel.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/83fb7d7e810919ea77cf2abf21635546.gif Like THis @mlarionov

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) page from the discord.js guide about reaction collectors, it tells you everything you need to know. You can read [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) for more info about the .createReactionCollector() method.

There are multiple ways to acheive what you want once you make the reaction collector but I beleive the easiest would look something like this:

```
message.channel.send('your_message_here')
  .then(async function(message) {
    await message.react('');
    await message.react('');
    await message.react('‍');

    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return ['', '', '‍'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === ogauthor
    }
    
    const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter)
    
    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
      async function collect() {
        if (!user.bot) {
          if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            //code here
          }
          //repeat this for the rest of your reactions
          reaction.users.remove(user.id) //you can remove the reaction once they react to it and their name is added.
        }
      }
      collect()
    });
  })
```

One problem is that this will run forever so you should add a timer to it.

Comment: So i get that you can collect the user who reacts but how do i call it to an embed? What im trying to achive is like this https://i.gyazo.com/83fb7d7e810919ea77cf2abf21635546.gif but for voting purposes. SO you type the command embed pops up says something like Vote user in the clan  Yes or NO so Like if i click "" my name shows up inside that embed and if someone click  then there name shows up in a different field. Maybe next to the first field.

Comment: @JamesLewis You can store people's names and just edit the value of the field once they react. [Dorian349's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081641/13981294) pretty much explains what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your code and added code to track votes, edit the embed and check when the votes reach the threshold.

## Demonstration

[image: Discord embed demonstration]

## Code

```js
message.delete({ timeout: 100 });
if (!args[0]) return message.reply('You need to supply the question');

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(args.join(' '))
  .setDescription('Poll created by ' + message.author.tag)
  .addField('Status', 'Voting is currently open.')
  .setColor('#ffd700')
  .attachFiles(new Discord.MessageAttachment('https://i.imgur.com/QUmbq9o.png', 'thumbnail.png'))
  .setThumbnail('attachment://thumbnail.png')
  .setFooter('Bot created by James (Rock)₇₇₇');

message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
  await msg.react('');
  await msg.react('');
  await msg.react('');
  await msg.react('️');

  const threshold = 1;

  async function stop(result) {
    collector.stop();

    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(msg.embeds[0]);

    newEmbed.title = newEmbed.title + ' [CLOSED]';
    newEmbed.fields[0] = { name: 'Status', value: 'Voting is now closed.\n' + result };
    newEmbed.setThumbnail('attachment://thumbnail.png');
    await msg.edit(newEmbed);

    msg.reactions.removeAll();
  }

  async function update() {
    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(embed);

    const userYes = (votes[''].size === 0)? '-' : [...votes['']];
    const userNo = (votes[''].size === 0)? '-' : [...votes['']];
    const userUnsure = (votes[''].size === 0)? '-' : [...votes['']];

    newEmbed.addFields(
      { name: `User Yes (${votes[''].size}/${threshold})`, value: userYes, inline: true },
      { name: `User No (${votes[''].size}/${threshold})`, value: userNo, inline: true },
      { name: 'User Unsure', value: userUnsure, inline: true }
    );

    await msg.edit(newEmbed);

    if (votes[''].size >= threshold) {
      await stop('This answer is good enough to get accepted and an upvote.');
      // do something
    } else if (votes[''].size >= threshold) {
      await stop('This answer is not good enough to get accepted and an upvote.');
      // do something
    }
  }

  const votes = {
    '': new Set(),
    '': new Set(),
    '': new Set(),
    '️': new Set()
  };

  update();

  const collector = msg.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => !user.bot , { dispose: true });

  collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (['', '', '', '️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)) {
      const userReactions = msg.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(user.id));

      for (const userReaction of userReactions.values()) {
        if (userReaction.emoji.name !== reaction.emoji.name || reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
          userReaction.users.remove(user.id);
          votes[userReaction.emoji.name].delete(user);
        }
      }

      votes[reaction.emoji.name].add(user);
    } else {
      reaction.remove();
    }

    update();
  });

  collector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
    votes[reaction.emoji.name].delete(user);

    update();
  });
});
```

Comment: Bro for some reason i'm receiving an error. When i excute the code it showing a discord is not defined in cmd prompt.

Comment: Did you include `const Discord = require('discord.js');` at the very top of the file?

Comment: yes i have updated my code to match exactly what i have!

Comment: You need `const Discord = require('discord.js');` at the very top of your file.

Comment: I got it bro! Thank you so much :)

Comment: I have updated it so if anyone in the future needs it they can grab it! Thanks @daemon Beast

Comment: My pleasure. Also, try not to copy code from answers back into your question because it can invalidate the question, instead mark the answer that worked as accepted.

Comment: why would i run into a issue where i have to input !apply enter !apply for the dm to work?

Comment: I have to enter the cmd twice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reaction Collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector) for this case to listen to reactions and list them depending on it.

I've made the code below, it works as expected:

[image]

```js
message.delete({ timeout: 100 });
if (!args[0]) return message.reply('You need to supply the question');

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle(args.join(' '))
   .setDescription('Poll created by ' + message.author.tag)
   .setColor('#ffd700')
   .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/QUmbq9o.png")
   .addFields({name: "User Yes", value: 'None'}, {name: "User No", value: 'None'}, {name: "User Hum", value: 'None'})
   .setFooter("Bot created by James (Rock)₇₇₇");


message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
    await msg.react('');
    await msg.react('');
    await msg.react('');
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return ["", "", ""].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
    };

    const collector = await msg.createReactionCollector(filter);

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {

      const reactionsList = ["", "", ""];
      const fieldTitle = ["User Yes", "User No", "User Hum"];

      var reactions = reaction.message.reactions.cache.array();

      for(var reactionID in reactions) {
        for (var i = 0; i < reactionsList.length; i++) {
          if(reactionsList[i] === reaction.emoji.name){
            let fieldDescription = user.id + "\n";
             var users = reactions[reactionID].users.cache.array();
             for(var userID in users){
               if(users[userID].id === client.user.id || users[userID].id === user.id) continue;
               fieldDescription += users[userID].id + "\n";
             }
             embed.spliceFields(i, 1, {name: fieldTitle[i], value: fieldDescription})
          }
        }
      }

      msg.edit(embed);

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  PermissionFlagsBits,
  ChatInputCommandInteraction,
  Client,
  EmbedBuilder,
} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("test")
    .setDescription("Poll Embed")
    .setDMPermission(false)
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator)
    .addStringOption((options) =>
      options
        .setName("frage")
        .setDescription("Stelle eine Frage")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),

  /**
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} interaction
   */
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const args = interaction.options.getString("frage");

    let embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(args)
      .setDescription(`Umfrage erstellt von ${interaction.user}`)
      .setColor("Blue")
      .setThumbnail(interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
      .setTimestamp()
      .addFields(
        { name: "Zugesagt", value: "None", inline: true },
        { name: "Abgesagt", value: "None", inline: true },
        { name: "Unsicher", value: "None", inline: true }
      )
      .setFooter({ text: "ClanBot" });
    interaction.reply({ content: " Befehl ausgeführt", ephemeral: true });
    interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }).then(async (interaction) => {
      await interaction.react("");
      await interaction.react("");
      await interaction.react("");
      await interaction.react("️");

      const threshold = 1;

      async function stop(result) {
        collector.stop();

        const newEmbed = new EmbedBuilder(interaction.embeds[0]);

        newEmbed.title = newEmbed.title + " [CLOSED]";
        newEmbed.fields[0] = {
          name: "Status",
          value: "Voting iste beendet.\n" + result,
        };
        newEmbed.setThumbnail(interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }));
        await interaction.edit({ embeds: [newEmbed] });

        interaction.reactions.removeAll();
      }

      async function update() {
        const newEmbed = new EmbedBuilder({ embeds: [embed] });

        const userYes = votes[""].size === 0 ? "-" : [...votes[""]];
        const userNo = votes[""].size === 0 ? "-" : [...votes[""]];
        const userUnsure = votes[""].size === 0 ? "-" : [...votes[""]];

        newEmbed.addFields(
          {
            name: `Zugesagt (${votes[""].size}/${threshold})`,
            value: userYes,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: `Abgesagt (${votes[""].size}/${threshold})`,
            value: userNo,
            inline: true,
          },
          { name: "Unsicher", value: userUnsure, inline: true }
        );

        await interaction.edit({ embeds: [newEmbed] });

        if (votes[""].size >= threshold) {
          await stop("Die Anrwort ist gut und wurde Aktzeptiert.");
          // do something
        } else if (votes[""].size >= threshold) {
          await stop("Die Antwort ist nicht gut und wurde nicht aktzeptiert.");
          // do something
        }
      }

      const votes = {
        "": new Set(),
        "": new Set(),
        "": new Set(),
        "️": new Set(),
      };

      update();

      const collector = interaction.createReactionCollector(
        (reaction, user) => !user.bot,
        { dispose: true }
      );

      collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
        if (["", "", "", "️"].includes(reaction.emoji.name)) {
          const userReactions = interaction.reactions.cache.filter((reaction) =>
            reaction.users.cache.has(user.id)
          );

          for (const userReaction of userReactions.values()) {
            if (
              userReaction.emoji.name !== reaction.emoji.name ||
              reaction.emoji.name === "️"
            ) {
              userReaction.users.remove(user.id);
              votes[userReaction.emoji.name].delete(user);
            }
          }

          votes[reaction.emoji.name].add(user);
        } else {
          interaction.reaction.remove();
        }

        update();
      });

      collector.on("remove", (reaction, user) => {
        votes[reaction.emoji.name].delete(user);

        update();
      });
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.